# Jquery : Save the data w.r.t page on client side using jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

As we know Jqgrid provides server side paging.But, in our scenario we need client side pagination i.e, data to be stored locally (on client side) per page along with the checkbox selection state.

for example, lets consider the page size to be 5. After adding 5 records , the focus should directly navigate to the 2nd page. Fine,this is already happening. But the problem is when we fill the data in page 1 and navigate to page 2 , the data gets wiped out from page 1 & vice versa.

I want to store the records data per page i.e, with Key = PageNumber & Value= Data of the 5 records (as an array) locally on client side. And should be able to retrieve them whenever navigating throught the pages and load the appropriate data on that page.

Any pointers on how to accomplish this would be very usefull..

Thankyou

Comment: Sorry, but it's not full clear what you want. You wrote about "adding 5 records" and "the data gets wiped out from page 1" which is very unclear. It seems that your server should just return *all items at once* and you should use `loadonce: true` option. In the case the data loaded at the first (and at the only) call to the sever will be paged, sorted and filtered/searched *locally*.

Comment: Hi Oleg,
Nothing is been yet saved to the database. Everything is on the client side. When he adds records in the page 1 (say) and fill the column data and navigates to next page fill the data there , & navigate back to page 1 .. the data wipes out..
I need something like persisting the data while navigating on client side..

Comment: The data in jqGrid are persisting if you use correct datatype and fill the data in correct way. It's not a common problem which you describe, but *some problem in your code*. Could you append the text of your question with the code which you use to create the grid and to fill it with data?

Comment: dataType : json
is been used, does this data type help in client storage or do I need to change it to local ? But if i change the data type to local, then lot of code has to be changed in this scenario..
Any other alternative for this ?

Comment: **You should just append JavaScript code which you use to the text of your question**. You can't use `dataType : json`. If you load data using *separate* `jQuery.ajax` call then the option of `$.ajax` will be `dataType: "json"` and jqGrid should use `datatype: "local"`. If jqGrid should load the data then you should use `datatype: "json"` and `loadonce: true`. So **you should be exact**.  Moreover I asked you **how you fill the data in the grid**. It could be very important. So you need post *the exact details of your implementation*.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to store the records data per page i.e, with Key = PageNumber & Value= Data of the 5 records (as an array) locally on client side. And should be able to retrieve them whenever navigating throught the pages and load the appropriate data on that page.

You don't have to worry about this i.e. maintaining what data belongs to which page, grid will take care of it.

If you have some dynamic data coming which you need to add in first page or second page conditinally, you should try updating the same data source array using [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) or `push`.